# io.jsonwebtoken.security.weakkeyexception: The verification key's size is 48 bits which is not secure enough for the HS256 algorithm

Tags: java, android, base64, jwt, token

I'm attempting to take a token from my web application's api and parse out the user id from it in android studio. I'm using jjwt to decode the token, but am running into this issue. I was reading online and the solutions said to make sure my 'secret-key' was in base 64, but it's still causing issues.

I tried using the encoder, and an online encoder and hardcoding the base-64 String of my 'secret', but still returns the same issues. 
A link to people having similar issues is found here
github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues/208

```
    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvText);

    final String token = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVjOWYzYWI2NzY2Mjg2NDYyNDY0YTczNCIsIm5hbWUiOiJSYW5keSIsImF2YXRhciI6Ii8vd3d3LmdyYXZhdGFyLmNvbS9hdmF0YXIvMTNhN2MyYzdkOGVkNTNkMDc2MzRkOGNlZWVkZjM0NTE_cz0yMDAmcj1wZyZkPW1tIiwiaWF0IjoxNTU0NTIxNjk1LCJleHAiOjE1NTQ1MjUyOTV9._SxRurShXS-SI3SE11z6nme9EoaD29T_DBFr8Qwngkg";
    final String secret = "secret";
    String secret64 = "c2VjcmV0";

    String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(secret.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);

    Jws<Claims> jws;
    try {
        jws = Jwts.parser()         // (1)

                .setSigningKey(secret64)       // (2)
                .parseClaimsJws(token); // (3)

        // we can safely trust the JWT

    }
    catch (JwtException ex) {       // (4)
        // we *cannot* use the JWT as intended by its creator
        tv.setText(ex.toString());
    }
```

Comment: What do you not understand? Your "secret" is 48 bits long, and the library is complaining about that.

Comment: The GitHub issue you almost posted a link to does not seem related.

Comment: I thought it was an issue with jjwt and base 64, as my error being returned before was speaking of bits as well, so I glossed over this error. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> The verification key's size is 48 bits

This statement tells the whole story . The `secret` key you've used is too short . If you are using `HS256` which is HMAC with `SHA-256` needs at least **256 bits** or larger MUST be used with the `HS256` algorithm .

As mentioned in [JSON Web Algorithms](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#page-7)

> the JSON Web Algorithms RFC 7518 states that a key of the same size as
> the hash output (for instance, 256 bits for "HS256") or larger MUST be
> used with the HS256 algorithm.

So change your key size and you are good to go

Comment: Oh.. Well, that makes sense.. I guess I didn't understand the error when I was first reading it, but I see my prominent mistake now. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

For testing purposes, if the idea is to generate 256 bits to be tested as a secret, a method like this can help:

```java
private String generateSafeToken() {
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[36]; // 36 bytes * 8 = 288 bits, a little bit more than
                                 // the 256 required bits 
    random.nextBytes(bytes);
    var encoder = Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding();
    return encoder.encodeToString(bytes);
}
```