# The signing key's size is 48 bits which is not secure enough for the HS256 algorithm

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

I'm this is my first time making a project that needs JWT authentication, I'm following [this](https://springframework.guru/jwt-authentication-in-spring-microservices-jwt-token/) tutorial, but I get the problem that my key must be higher than 256bits, I searched here and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55545957/io-jsonwebtoken-security-weakkeyexception-the-verification-keys-size-is-48-bit) post, however I'm new in this topic so I don't really know how to make it 256bits. Below is my code:

```
@Service
public class JwtGeneration implements IJwtGeneration {
    
    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    private String secret;
    
    @Value("${app.jwttoken.message}")
    private String message;
    
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> generateToken(User user) {
        String jwtToken="";
        jwtToken = Jwts.builder().setSubject(user.getUserName()).setIssuedAt(new Date()).signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, "secret").compact();
        Map<String, String> jwtTokenGen = new HashMap<>();
        jwtTokenGen.put("token", jwtToken);
        jwtTokenGen.put("message", message);
        return jwtTokenGen;
    }
    
}
```

How can I make it 256 bits?

Searching more, I found that I could try this:

```
@Service
public class JwtGeneration implements IJwtGeneration {
    
    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    private String secret;
    
    byte[] decodedKey = secret.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, 0, decodedKey.length, "HMACSHA256");
    
    @Value("${app.jwttoken.message}")
    private String message;
    
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> generateToken(User user) {
        String jwtToken="";
        jwtToken = Jwts.builder().setSubject(user.getUserName()).setIssuedAt(new Date()).signWith(key, SignatureAlgorithm.HS256).compact();
        Map<String, String> jwtTokenGen = new HashMap<>();
        jwtTokenGen.put("token", jwtToken);
        jwtTokenGen.put("message", message);
        return jwtTokenGen;
    }
    
}
```

But I still get error, how can I fix it?

**UPDATE**
This is the error message I get: "io.jsonwebtoken.security.WeakKeyException: The signing key's size is 48 bits which is not secure enough for the HS256 algorithm.  The JWT JWA Specification (RFC 7518, Section 3.2) states that keys used with HS256 MUST have a size >= 256 bits (the key size must be greater than or equal to the hash output size).  Consider using the io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys class's 'secretKeyFor(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)' method to create a key guaranteed to be secure enough for HS256.  See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7518#section-3.2 for more information.
at com.authdemo.AuthDemo.config.JwtGeneration.generateToken(JwtGeneration.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
at com.authdemo.AuthDemo.controller.UserController.loginUser(UserController.java:44) ~[classes/:na]"

I tried `SecretKey key = secretKeyFor(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)` but it didn't work.

Comment: Does your stack trace indicate that the error is occurring on the assignment to `jwtToken`?  I'm wondering if there might be some external method encountering that error.

Comment: I updated my question, the error occurs in the generation of token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I had to add to my pom the following dependencies: jjwt-impl and jjwt-jackson. Also I had to create my secret key as follows:

```
private String secret = "2D4A614E645267556B58703273357638792F423F4428472B4B6250655368566D";



@Value("${app.jwttoken.message}")
private String message;

@Override
public Map<String, String> generateToken(User user) {
    String jwtToken="";
    jwtToken = Jwts.builder().setSubject(user.getUserName()).setIssuedAt(new Date()).signWith(getSignInKey(),SignatureAlgorithm.HS256).compact();
    Map<String, String> jwtTokenGen = new HashMap<>();
    jwtTokenGen.put("token", jwtToken);
    jwtTokenGen.put("message", message);
    return jwtTokenGen;
}

private Key getSignInKey() {
    byte[] keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(secret);
    return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
}
```

Turns out I was using "secretkey" as my jwt.secret in application properties. And I was passing that variable alone. What I did now was use an online keygenerator and then created a function to convert it to a Key and then passed it to signWith() method.